# For Discourse is there an importer than can read from text files, like csv files?

Tags: import, discourse

If so this seem to be the simplest approach for importing data from other sources because I can extract data from the old forum without problem, the difficultly is getting an import into discourse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up writing one myself, expect this is of most use to other Java developers moving relatively small forums to Discourse from another forum. In my case i was importing from JForum but the tool is not JForum specific it just works from .csv files.

https://meta.discourse.org/t/discoursetransfer-simple-java-tool-for-import/138800

Answer (score 0):

Discourse has an API which allows creating users, posts, uploads etc.
The documentation is at [docs.discourse.org](https://docs.discourse.org/#tag/Users/operation/listUserBadges)

There's also this F# program, but last update was in 2016: https://github.com/Viir/import-to-discourse